# Can a compiler automatically detect pure functions without the type information about purity?

Tags: c, gcc, haskell, compiler-construction, d

So I'm arguing with my friend who claims that a compiler like GCC can detect a pure function automatically without any type information. I doubt that.

Languages like D or Haskell have purity in their type systems and a programmer explicitly defines what function is pure or not. A pure function has no side effects and can therefore very easily be parallelized.

So the question is: Is this all necessary or not? Could a compiler detect purity, without any meta or type information, just by assuming that anything that does IO or accesses global variables automatically is not pure?

Comment: Well, both answers would be interesting - if it would be possible in theory and if any production ready compiler does something like that.

Comment: Also, is the question about whether compilers *would be able* to detect pure functions or whether compilers *actually apply* such a detection algorithm?

Comment: If it wasn't for separate compilation, C could have perfect knowledge of what is pure and impure. Just because that information isn't called "type" doesn't mean a compiler can't be aware of it. The problem with separate compilation - functions linked in from object files or whatever don't include purity metadata. Even if they did, that information isn't available until linking, so the compiler doesn't see it. Within a particular source file, though, the compiler may identify functions that don't have any possible source of impurity and may use that information for certain optimisations.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sure, you can detect pure functions in some cases. For instance,

```
int f(int x)
{
    return x*2;
}
```

can be detected as pure with simple static analysis. The difficulty is doing this in general, and detecting interfaces which use "internal" state but are externally pure is basically impossible.

GCC does have the [warning options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) `-Wsuggest-attribute=pure` and `-Wsuggest-attribute=const`, which suggest functions that might be candidates for the `pure` and `const` [attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html). I'm not sure whether it opts to be conservative (i.e. missing many pure functions, but never suggesting it for a non-pure function) or lets the user decide.

Note that GCC's definition of `pure` is "depending only on arguments and global variables":

> Many functions have no effects except the return value and their return value depends only on the parameters and/or global variables. Such a function can be subject to common subexpression elimination and loop optimization just as an arithmetic operator would be. These functions should be declared with the attribute `pure`.
>
> — [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

Strict purity, i.e. the same results for the same arguments in all circumstances, is represented by the `const` attribute, but such a function cannot even dereference a pointer passed to it. So the parallelisation opportunities for `pure` functions are limited, but much fewer functions can be `const` compared to the pure functions you can write in a language like Haskell.

By the way, automatically parallelising pure functions is not as easy as you might think; the hard part becomes deciding *what* to parallelise. Parallelise computations that are too cheap, and overhead makes it pointless. Don't parallelise enough, and you don't reap the benefits. I don't know of any practical functional language implementation that does automatic parallelisation for this reason, although libraries like [repa](http://repa.ouroborus.net/) parallelise many operations behind the scenes without explicit parallelism in the user code.

Comment: Also, for languages like C and C++, the compiler is expected to produce assembly that pretty much reflects the exact structure of the program given, so I don't think it would be allowed to apply optimizations that are as intrusive as automatic parallelization. By the way, do you know whether GCC applies such detection? If yes, for what purpose?

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: C has the "as-if" rule, which allows the implementation to do anything it wants so long as a conforming program cannot distinguish the result. Parallelising the execution of pure functions would fall under this umbrella.

Comment: I've just expanded my answer to answer the GCC question.

Comment: A wise compiler, when guessing about the "purity" of a function (for the sake of optimization), will allow false negatives (might miss chances for optimization), but not false positives (otherwise would perform erroneous optimization).

Comment: @ehird: That's true, but if a C compiler automatically created threads behind your back, nobody would go near it.

Comment: @PeterAlexander: I dunno — if someone offered me a C compiler which automatically parallelised programs with good efficiency and low overhead, I wouldn't say no. Of course, such a thing is a silver bullet.

Comment: are you sure about this const func == strict purity claim? .. i just get " error: non-member function cannot have 'const' qualifier" ... it works on c++ class member functions, but then it means the non-mutable members of the object pointed to by this can not be modified.

Comment: @WillemHengeveld I don’t know if it’s still relevant to you but it might be to other people who come here: there’s a difference between `const` as you are using and the GCC `const` attribute, [`__attribute__((const))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bconst_007d-function-attribute-2504).

Answer (score 13):

There is another problem. Consider

```
int isthispure(int i) {
   if (false) return getchar();
   return i + 42;
}
```

The function is effectively pure, though it contains impure code, but this code cannot be reached.
Now suppose `false` is replaced by `g(i)` but we know quite sure that g(i) is false (for example, g might check if its argument is a [Lychrel number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number)).
To prove that isthispure is indeed pure, the compiler would have to prove that no Lychrel numbers exist.

(I admit that this is a quite theoretical consideration. One could also decide that if a function contains any impure code, it is itself impure. But this is not justified by the C type system, IMHO.)

Comment: +1, but actually the compiler would only need to check that the integers ranging from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX` are not Lycrel numbers, which is a much easier task than proving that none exist. A good static analyzer could certainly apply a brute-force approach to functions whose argument space is smaller than some bound `M` (e.g. `M=1<<32` or so).

Comment: Even Haskell doesn't *exactly* assert that there is definite purity or impurity. When a function uses `unsafePerformIO`, the author may be wrong that nothing impure occurs. Also, there are functions with return type `IO a` which perform no IO.

Comment: @amindfv: Well, `unsafePerformIO` isn't "really" part of Haskell, even if it is a standard part of the FFI.

Comment: @ehird: Is it part of the FFI? It's in System.IO, where all of the basic file handle stuff is

Comment: @amindfv: Actually, it's in System.IO.Unsafe; however, the structure of the standard base package doesn't mirror the structure of the standard, it's a superset. `unsafePerformIO` is in the FFI addendum to Haskell 98; the FFI was included in Haskell 2010, but without `unsafePerformIO` (there's a less powerful `unsafeLocalState` instead).

Comment: @R. I bet you can't do that for only 10 ints (say from 190 to 200) in reasonable time. There are Lycrel candidates (was it 192 or 196, dunno at the moment), where your personal computer may be busy a year, or so and still will not have proved that it is none.

Comment: On the opposite side from unsafePerformIO, there's IO actions that turn out to be completely pure. For example `return 0` - the type is `IO Int` (or `IO Num` or whatever), but there are no effects. This is very much like the C example for this question - especially if we add some genuinely effectful action that will never be used such as `if False then getChar else (return ' ')`. Haskell code can appear effectful yet have no effects too - it's just that the deception is explicit in the type rather than implicit.

Answer (score 4):

Determining if a function is pure (even in the limited sense used by GCC) is equivalent to the halting problem, so the answer is "not for arbitrary functions." It is possible to automatically detect that some functions are pure, others are not pure, and flag the rest as "unknown", which allows for automatic parallelization in some cases.

In my experience, even programmers aren't very good at figuring out such things, so I want the type system to help keep track of it *for me*, not just for the optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered while writing an article [comparing C# and C++ performance](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212856/Head-to-head-benchmark-Csharp-vs-NET) that Visual C++ can indeed detect a pure function of moderate complexity, while calling a [function that computed a polynomial](http://dan.corlan.net/bench.html#C).

I called the polynomial function in a loop to eat up time on the clock. The compiler optimized the call to run once before the loop started and re-use the result within the loop. To do that it would have to know that there are no side-effects.

I must say though, is nice to be able to *guarantee* that the compiler can do an optimization, by marking a function as pure, and it serves as a form of documentation, too.