# How to express immutability guarantees

Tags: f#

The code below shows a situation where some record is being processed by 2 functions of the same signature (`RwA -> RwA`). Yet, depending on the implementation of that changer function, the data passed to it might be changed or not.

In a larger project, such things can be costly. Maybe during maintenance or during optimization, the implementation of a function is changed or more changer functions are being added, the program still looks the same, yet suddenly behaves in unexpected ways.

So the question is: Is there any way to render the code in this sample such, that it is obvious (and compiler checked), that a function of type `RwAChanger` may or may not change the data it is passed as a parameter?

Please do not reply "don't use arrays", as this could be large amounts of data, such as vertices of a 3D mesh or alike, where performance would be an issue.
Also, I am sure it is possible to find other examples, which do not involve arrays which produce the same type of problems.

```
// A record with arrays...
type RwA =
    {
        A : int array
        I : int array
    }

let x = [| for i in 0..10 -> i |]

let init a =
    { A = a; I = Array.map (fun v -> -v ) a }

// This function creates a new array as member A in RwA
let change (o : RwA) : RwA =
    { o with A = Array.map (fun v -> v + 42) o.A }

// This function modifies the value of the array in member A of an RwA instance.
let change2 (o: RwA) : RwA =
    o.A.[0] <- 666
    o

let dump (o : RwA) =
    printfn "{ A = %A; I = %A; }" o.A o.I
    o

let dumpA (a : int array) : int array =
    printfn "x = %A" x
    a

// Is there a way to express a contract about immutability?
type RwAChanger = RwA -> RwA

let transmogrify (changer : RwAChanger) a =
    a
    |> dumpA
    |> init
    |> dump
    |> changer
    |> dump
    |> ignore

let test() = 
    transmogrify change x
    dumpA x |> ignore
    transmogrify change2 x    
    dumpA x |> ignore

do test()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure F# doesn't support code contracts.

Comment: @Vesa.A.J.K I think you didn't read the question closely enough. 'Please do not reply "don't use arrays"'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the question is: Is there any way to render the code in this sample such, that it is obvious (and compiler checked), that a function of type RwAChanger may or may not change the data it is passed as a parameter?

The answer is basically yes; it is often possible to encode properties such as whether an object may or may not be changed by a particular function using types.  The essential technique is to use *abstract types*. You define a set of types, one type corresponding to each different kind of access you wish to distinguish, and associated operations on those types.

In this particular case, for example, you could define two types.  First you would define one type corresponding to a read-only view:

```
// Read-only objects
module RA =
  type RA
  val change: RA -> RA
  // and other operations on read-only objects
```

What is important in the above signature is that the type `RA` is left abstract.  Only the operations defined in the signature can be used to manipulate objects of type `RA`.

Then you would also define another type corresponding to a read-write view:

```
// Read-write objects
module RwA =
  type RwA
  val change: RwA -> RwA
  // and other operations on read-write objets
```

This signature also leaves the type `RwA` abstract.  In addition, you would also allow a `RwA` object to be viewed as a `RA` object:

```
val readonly: RwA -> RA
```

But not vice versa!

Now, a function that only uses read operations, would be given a type that takes `RA` type objects, while a function that uses write operations, would be given a type that takes `RwA` objects.

One inconvenience with the above scheme is that in order to use a read-only operation on a read-write object, one needs to explicitly convert the read-write object to a read-only object using the `readonly` operation:

```
RwA.readonly (x: RwA.RwA) |> RA.change
```

There is a trick, called *phantom types*, that can often eliminate the need for such explicit conversions.  Instead of defining multiple abstract types, one adds one or more extra type parameters to an abstract type to encode the desired properties.

As an example of phantom types, let's define a type, `RWArray<'rw, 't>`, for read-write arrays, that allows one to distinguish whether or not an operation can modify the elements of the array.  First, here is the signature:

```
// RWArray.fsi

type R
type W
type RWArray<'rw, 't>

module RWArray =
  val zeroCreate: int -> RWArray<W, 't>
  val readonly: RWArray<_, 't> -> RWArray<R, 't>
  val length: RWArray<_, 't> -> int
  val get: RWArray<_, 't> -> int -> 't
  val set: RWArray<W, 't> -> int -> 't -> unit
```

The `RWArray<'rw, 't>` type has the type parameter `'rw` to encode whether an object can be modified or not.  In this case, there is only one mutating operation, the `set` operation, which requires the type parameter to be unifiable with `W`.  Other operations allow the type parameter to be any type.  In other words, the read-only operations are polymorphic with respect to the phantom type parameter `'rw`.

Take a moment to figure out (or try using a compiler) what the types of the following function definitions would be:

```
let modify xs x2x =
  for i=0 to RWArray.length xs - 1 do
    RWArray.set xs i << x2x <| RWArray.get xs i

let map xs x2y =
  let ys = RWArray.zeroCreate (RWArray.length xs)
  for i=0 to RWArray.length xs - 1 do
    RWArray.set ys i << x2y <| RWArray.get xs i
  ys
```

As you can see, the type of the `modify` operation requires a writable array, while the `map` operation does not.  Now, when defining higher-order operations, one can constrain functions given as parameters to not allow mutation of the array.  Here is an example:

```
let sillyExample (effect: RWArray<R, int> -> unit) : unit =
  let rwa = RWArray.zeroCreate 1
  RWArray.set rwa 0 31
  effect (RWArray.readonly rwa)
  RWArray.set rwa 0 (RWArray.get rwa 0 + 10)
  effect (RWArray.readonly rwa)
```

What is known in the above function definition is that the calls to `effect` cannot modify the array given as a parameter (well, without using reflection).  Note that in the above, the `readonly` operation needs to be used to give the array to the `effect` function, but the call to `RWArray.get` doesn't require it.

One could avoid the use of `readonly` by using an additional type for the effect operation that would require the effect to be polymorphic with respect to the `'rw` parameter:

```
type Effect =
  abstract Invoke: RWArray<'rw, int> -> unit

let sillyExample2 (effect: Effect) : unit =
  let rwa = RWArray.zeroCreate 1
  RWArray.set rwa 0 31
  effect.Invoke rwa
  RWArray.set rwa 0 (RWArray.get rwa 0 + 10)
  effect.Invoke rwa
```

The above variation has essentially the same properties as the previous variation.  In other words, it is known that the calls to `effect.Invoke` cannot modify the array.

The implementation of the `RWArray` module and associated types is straightforward:

```
// RWArray.fs

type R = | R
type W = | W
type RWArray<'rw, 't> = {RWArray: array<'t>}

module RWArray =
  let zeroCreate n : RWArray<W, 't> = {RWArray = Array.zeroCreate n}
  let readonly (rwa: RWArray<_, _>) : RWArray<R, _> = {RWArray = rwa.RWArray}
  let length rwa = rwa.RWArray.Length
  let get rwa i = rwa.RWArray.[i]
  let set (rwa: RWArray<W, _>) i x = rwa.RWArray.[i] <- x
```

The reason behind the term "phantom type" is that the type parameter `'rw` only appears as a type parameter.  As you can see, it is not used on the right hand side of the `RWArray<'rw, 't>` type definition.

An actual implementation of this approach would likely define many more operation.

There are many interesting papers that describe techniques for encoding properties using ML-style type systems.  I just mention one paper: [No-Longer-Foreign: Teaching an ML compiler
to speak C “natively”](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~blume/papers/nlffi-entcs.pdf).  I'll also mention one post I wrote years ago: [Phantom booleans for encoding arbitrary finite relations](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.functional/W7eHFNfQH9w).

**Here is an exercise:**  Design a more refined version of read-write arrays such that one can specify functions that can read the array length and

- nothing else, or
- can also write to an array, or
- can also only read from an array, or
- can also both read from and write to an array.

Comment: When I experimented a bit further I came to a similar - if a bit more low tech - approach. I also added modules and made the read only stuff visible to developers. At the expense of a copy of the input value, I then simply allowed both types of changers but for the "invariant" use case, I do a deep copy first. All that wrapped such that no matter how people write the changer, the effects to the outside would be identical. Of course, being able to avoid the copy operation, this solution here is preferable.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a way to tell the compiler that an existing mutable type should be made immutable, nor use Code Contracts as @mydogisbox mentions in a comment.

You may however be able to use an [`ImmutableArray<T>`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/06/24/please-welcome-immutablearray.aspx) from the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable/) package in your `RwA` record. The performance difference for array access should be minimal.

Comment: Would that not hint to a lack of a keyword like "const"? Or the lack of a function classifier such as "reentrant" or alike? Might it be that the language designers trusted too much in the "functional side" of the language? I can think of scenarios where both kinds of behavior would be acceptable (modify if arrays are too large to produce copies, immutable, if e.g. stuff is done concurrently). But not being able to define which one is the desired behavior leads to problems imho.

Comment: I can't speak for F# language designers, but what seems to me is that the type itself can specify the contract. Array is mutable (but you obviously don't have to mutate it), ImmutableArray is immutable. If you need to use both, you can for example create two variants for `RwA` (one using mutable arrays, one immutable). Then you can say that function `change` uses immutable version and `change2` requires the mutable one. The function's signature then says how it can behave.

Comment: Keywords as you propose would work too, but are unnecessary addition next to the type system. You (or more specifically language designers) have to solve the same issues, for example how far does the immutability go. Only the top level? We already have that. One level next? Then you have the same issue for nested objects. All the way down? That's a harsh constraint, because for example some of the immutable collection implementations use mutable trees under the hood for performance reasons, while still obeying the immutability contract on the highest level.

Comment: And there are also different kinds of immutability, for which you would need separate keywords, should the language support them all: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx

Comment: I see the problem in the context of the whole life cycle of a program, which possibly is produced by (changing) teams and maintained by yet another bunch of guys. One guy would be responsible to do a "design" in the start of the programs life cycle. One such design element could be a pattern as shown in the original post. "There is a transformation function which does things to the RwA. And what it does exactly is determined by the RwAChanger compatible functions, of which there will be several." Such a design should not break at the moment when the RwA type gets changed.

Comment: Maybe a Monadic or array member is added later. Maybe the program is modified to use the data concurrenty and some changer functions make that impossible. Or the maintainer was not aware that they are not allowed to do this (or that), as in modify in place or do a copy. All this ambiguity could of course be handled in text (as I do now). But usually text is what is never read. Compiler errors are usuallly noticed ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a compiler error that distinguishes between changed and unchanged values, that pretty much implies that you *cannot* use the same signature for both kinds of functions.

So you cannot use:

```
type RwAChanger = RwA -> RwA
```

But you could have something like this instead:

```
type RwAChanger = RwA -> Changed RwA
type RwAUnchanger = RwA -> Unchanged RwA
```

which would indicate exactly what the function did. To use your examples:

```
type Changed<'T> = Changed of 'T
type Unchanged<'T> = Unchanged of 'T

let change2 (o: RwA) : RwA =
    o.A.[0] <- 666
    Changed o

let dump (o : RwA) =
    printfn "{ A = %A; I = %A; }" o.A o.I
    Unchanged o
```

You could also create some helpers to do type-safe `map` and `bind`. Here's an example of a little library:

```
module ChangeLib =

   type Changed<'T> = Changed of 'T
   type Unchanged<'T> = Unchanged of 'T

   type Changer<'T> = 'T -> Changed<'T>
   type Unchanger<'T> = 'T -> Unchanged<'T>

   let mapC f (Changed v) = Changed (f v) 
   let mapU f (Unchanged v) = Unchanged (f v) 

   /// if input is Unchanged and f returns a Changed, 
   /// the whole expression is Changed
   let bindUC (f:'a Changer) (Unchanged v) = f v 

   /// if input is Unchanged and f returns a Unchanged, 
   /// the whole expression is Unchanged
   let bindUU (f:'a Unchanger) (Unchanged v) = f v 

   /// if input is Changed and f returns a Unchanged, 
   /// the whole expression is Changed
   let bindCU (f:'a Unchanger) (Changed v) = 
        let (Unchanged u) = f v 
        Changed u

   /// if input is Changed and f returns a Changed, 
   /// the whole expression is Changed
   let bindCC (f:'a Changer) (Changed v) = f v
```

Here's an example of using that library:

```
module Example =       
    open ChangeLib

    let change (o: int[]) =
        o.[0] <- 42
        Changed o

    let copy (o: int[]) =
        let o' = o |> Array.map (fun i -> i + 1)
        Unchanged o'

    let dump (o: int[])=
        printfn "%A" o
        Unchanged o

    // has signature "int[] -> Changed int[]"
    let transmogrifyWithChanges x = 
        x 
        |> change
        |> bindCU dump

    // has signature "int[] -> Unchanged int[]"        
    let transmogrifyWithoutChanges x =
        x
        |> copy
        |> bindUU dump

    // mixing and matching will preserve state
    // so this function returns a Changed
    // and has signature "int[] -> Changed int[]"        
    let transmogrify x =
        x
        |> transmogrifyWithoutChanges
        |> bindUC transmogrifyWithChanges

    // do some tests            
    let a = [| 1;2;3 |]

    let changedA = 
        a |> transmogrifyWithChanges

    let unchangedA = 
        a |> transmogrifyWithoutChanges

    let changedA2 = 
        a |> transmogrify
```

Yes, it's awkward to have to use different kinds of `bind` functions, but that's the price you pay if you want compiler errors!

There are probably tricks with overloads or inlining that will allow you to have all the bind functions have the same name, but personally, I like the explicitness of having the function
name indicate the types.

As to performance, I don't think that wrapping the array will cause a big penalty.

Comment: I like to use similar wrappers as well, but what prevents me to break the contract here by writing something like `let xform (o: int[]) = o.[0] <- 42; Unchanged o`? It doesn't have to be malicious, it could happen with an automatic refactoring, a copy-paste maybe.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, nothing prevents you from returning the wrong type accidentally. And having the compiler automatically detect contract breaking like this is [a hard problem in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760956/can-a-compiler-automatically-detect-pure-functions-without-the-type-information).

If you want true immutability, don't use structures like arrays! But then you don't get the performance benefits either.